hosts.deny file breaks when I edit it with python- why? and how do I edit the file with python without losing functionality?
I've started monitoring system logs on my ubuntu sever and noticed thousands of failed ssh attempts from ips all over the world. I wrote a simple python script to track the ips and then edit them into my hosts.deny file to at least do something about it.
but when I ran my script I couldn't ssh into the server anymore. so I restored hosts.deny with a backup I had made- it worked again.
so I checked all my code. over and over. couldn't find anything wrong.
so then I decided to run a little test.
starting with the original hosts.deny file, I wrote this function in python:
def test():
   with open('/etc/hosts.deny', 'r') as file:
      data = file.read()
   with open('/etc/hosts.deny', 'w') as file:
      file.write(data)

this function does NOTHING. all it does is read the file, and then rewrite the file with the same contents. in theory, nothing at all should happen.
but when I run it- I can't ssh into my server anymore. replace hosts.deny with the backup file and Boom works again.
I assume there's something happening on a lower level that I'm unaware of? or some sort of character conversion that happens when you write the file with python instead of in the terminal?
also- i am aware of the existence of denyhosts, but i want the type of flexibility I can get from just writing my own pidly script, and it's a good learning exercize- so please help me and tell me why this happens?
appreciate it, thanks for reading

just a note: the python function here is all one line, i tried to add the correct indentation when typing it here, but it didn't come out correct. the script is written correctly and works as it should on my machine. i know because everytime i run it my ssh denies all connections

Are the contents of new file what you expect (cat, or diff with the original)? Are the permissions o the new file the same as on the old one (ls -l file  to check)?

an additional comment on ubfan1's suggestion - check the characters at the end of each line as well as any characters at the end of the file.  In some environments, lines end with just a cr while others require both a cr and lf.  Also at the end, some environments have a special character for 'end of   file'

permissions on original file:   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root
permissions after edit file   :   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root
so I guess that's not the problem.
as for End Of Line characters, python uses [\n] to denote EOL, and as far as I know it doesn't have a special character to denote EOF.
but I have zero clue of how Debian itself denotes those things. I would love to know, as It's possible those differences could be to blame for this behavior.
edit: looked it up, ran cat with -A so see the eols are all [$]. going to mess around with this new info and hope thats the fix

The diff command will note the extra ^M at the end of the line, invisible on what it prints out, but a clue as to the problem.

It was the End of Line characters, after all. Python knows how to switch its EOL into the system correct EOL. The problem was that I needed to explicitly add an EOL character to the end of each line, which I hadn't been doing.
Thanks for answering my question. I appreciate your replies. @ubfan1 @user628388

Can you explain your solution in more detail? I'm having trouble understanding how file.write(data) doesn't add the line terminations automatically. Did you diff the original and re-written files, and if so what did it report, exactly?

(I assume that to be a rhetorical question)
